# Как изменять код сайта с помощью F12

Tags: веб-программирование, google-chrome

Выложил сайт на localhost, и через F12 делаю изменения что бы посмотреть как поведет себя элемент.

Все эти изменение ( стили, новые элементы ) нужно будет переносить в IDE, возможно сделать так что бы они автоматически изменялись в файле?

Посоветуйте что-нибудь.

Comment: ну ладно еще пару галок для проверки ткнуть там или стилей написать. Но новые элементы в верстку писать? Вы какие то новые подходы  к разработке изобретаете.

Comment: Почему бы не писать всё сразу в IDE и просто тыкать F5 в браузере?

Comment: @andreymal так и делаю) Просто забирает время

Comment: а нельзя в редакторе менять и смотреть на изменения в браузере в runtime? вроде есть плагины для такого

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko Знаю, есть такое, но на одном экране не всегда удобно